# How to start KDE Plasma 5 on start up on FreeBSD 11.2?

Tags: freebsd, startup, plasma5

On FreeBSD 11.2 I have plasma5-plasma-workspace installed, along with x11/kde5 and sddm and I'd like to boot KDE Plasma 5 on boot. I've DuckDuckGo searched this topic but I haven't found any clear indication of how to do this. I tried to use my own noodle and add:

```
sddm_enable="YES"
dbus_enable="YES"
hald_enable="YES"
```

to my `/etc/rc.conf` file (based largely on [this article](https://community.kde.org/FreeBSD/Setup); I did originally also have `plasma_enable="YES"` as well in there, but I removed that when I found no such service in `/usr/local/etc/rc.d`), I realize the `dbus` and `hald` options lines may only apply to Plasma 4, but I thought better safe than sorry), yet KDE Plasma 5 is not started on boot. In `/usr/local/etc/sddm.conf` I also have:

```
# Name of session file for autologin session
Session=plasma.desktop

# Username for autologin session
User=fusion809
```

added under `[autologin]`.

Comment: I don't use KDE myself but I'm pretty sure you don't need to enable hald anymore.

Comment: Yep you were right, I was able to get it to work without hald.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out all I needed to do is install xf86-video-intel (for my Intel graphics card) in order to start Plasma 5 on boot. SDDM was auto-starting and autologging me into KDE Plasma 5, but unfortunately in the absence of this package the X.Org server crashed.

I should have checked if KDE Plasma 5 started using xinit (with the ~/.xinitrc `exec startkde`) before posting this question. Likewise I didn't need the `hald_enable` line in /etc/rc.conf.

Comment: Have you managed to get autologin working with sddm?

Comment: Yep, the autologin turned out to be working in itself, it was merely a driver issue stopping it from occurring. As soon as the autologin occurred the X.Org server crashed in the absence of the xf86-video-intel package.